# jar Файл не подключается к MySQL

Tags: mysql, jar

Написал программку на java, в коде прописал кнопку button, при нажатии на неё происходит подключение к БД MySQL но только из IDEA, а вот из jar файла подключение не происходит - почему объясните пожалуйста.
Прога запускается как фрейм.

Comment: Запустите программу через `cmd` и увидите из-за чего ошибка - `java -jar app.jar`. + прикрутите логгер аля `log4j2`.

Comment: cmd не показывает ошибки

Comment: Тогда верный путь к осваиванию библиотеки логгирования `log4j2`.

Comment: Подскажите плиз туториал по библиотеки логгирования.

Comment: http://javastudy.ru/log4j/log4j-hello-world-example/